# Reading data from serial port used >90% CPU

Tags: c#, .net, io, serial-port

I just created 1 simple C# app reading data from serial port (baudrate 57600). When I send file data from another computer through serial port, CPU worked >90%. How can I solve that ?
EDIT：

```
private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (temp_portname != null)
            {
                //ポート設定
                SerialPort.PortName = PORT1;
                SerialPort.BaudRate = 57600;
                //ポートを開く
                try
                {
                    SerialPort.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How were you reading it? (And why are you using a serial port for computer-to-computer communication?)

Comment: I just make some demo. I set baudrate and portname, then open port. I built event to read and show data then I deleted it. But nothing changed, CPU still work >90%.

Comment: Code speaks louder than words. Post some.

Comment: So.. this is all that you've got so far.. and your process runs at >90% CPU?

Comment: I had another complicated project with this problem so I created this simple app to find the way to solve and found that it had problem since the begining. That's all that make my process runs at >90% CPU when another computer send data.

Comment: Is this a USB serial port?  One on the motherboard?

Comment: this's between 2 computers, I used two USB to Serial adapters.